# How many zip codes are as large as 6000-0000, are even numbers, and have a 7 as their third digit?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, factorial

When they were first introduced, postal zip codes were five digit numbers, theoretically ranging from $00000$ to $99999$. (In reality, the lowest zip code was $00601$ for San Juan, Puerto Rico; the highest was $ 99950$ for Ketchikan, Alaska.) An additional four digit have been added, so each zip code is now a nine digit number. How many zip codes are at least as large as 60000-0000, are even numbers, and have a $7$ as their third digit?

Attempt: $A1*A2*A3*...*A9$ be a zip code. With $A3 = 7$. 
I don't know how to continue.

Can someone please help me with this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be at least as large as `60000-0000` the first place must be one of `6,7,8,9`.

To be an even number, the last place must be one of `0,2,4,6,8`.

For the third place to be `7` there's only one choice for the third place. `7`

The remaining six places can each be any of the ten digits, `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.

Each place is selected independently (digits can be repeated).

Count the ways to do this.

Comment: So the total N = 4*10*1*10*10*10*10*10*5 ?